# Get rid of decimals in currency formatter

Tags: yii2, formatter

Yii2 application with config:

```
...
'formatter' => [
        'locale' => 'ru_RU',
    ],
],
...
```

I call from the template `Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($item->price)` and got `12 675,00 ₽`. It is ok, but now I would like to get rid of the decimals at all.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(12675.00, null, [\NumberFormatter::MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS => 100])
```

[asCurrency()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asCurrency()-detail)

Comment: It works for me, but can I set this settings the application wide? In main config file as example? And after that use the function without so many parameters.

Comment: @GHopper. Normally application wide setting have decimal place configuration but still it is not dependent on locale or asCurrency(). Second If you are sure there is never decimal place in price then make a global function like `asCurrency()` and place Yii's asCurrency inside with above configuration. Third approach give application wide setting of decimal place make custom function to handle decimal. For now preferred approach is second one.